# Complex equations $z^3+i=0$ and $z^4+z^2+1=0$

Tags: complex-analysis

Find the solutions of this complex equations:

(a) $z^3+i=0$

(b) $z^4+z^2+1=0$

My answer:

(a)

$z^3=-i$

$x=0,  y=-1$

$r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=1$

$\theta=arctan \ ({y\over x})=arctan \ ({-1\over 0})$

$=arctan \ ({-\infty})={\pi\over 2}$

So

$z=r^{1\over 3}(cos {{{\pi\over 2}+2k\pi}\over 3}+isin {{{\pi \over 2}+2k\pi}\over 3})$

$z=(cos {{\pi+4k\pi}\over 6}+isin {{\pi+4k\pi}\over 6})$

when $k=0$

$z_1=cos{\pi\over 6}+isin{\pi\over 6}$

when $k=1$

$z_2=cos{5\pi\over 6}+isin{5\pi\over 6}$

when $k=2$

$z_3=cos{9\pi\over 6}+isin{9\pi\over 6}$

$=cos{3\pi\over 2}+isin{3\pi\over 2}$

True?

---

(b)

Let $z^2=x$

$z^4+z^2+1=x^2+x+1=0$

$a=1, \  b=1, \  c=1$

$x_1={{-1+\sqrt{3}i}\over 2}$

$x_2={{-1-\sqrt{3}i}\over 2}$

$z^2=x$ so $z=\sqrt{x}$

So

$z_1=\sqrt{{{-1+\sqrt{3}i}\over 2}}$

$z_2=\sqrt{{{-1-\sqrt{3}i}\over 2}}$

True ?

Thanks.

Comment: Do they both have to hold or are they separate problems?

Comment: Sorry, I don't speak English well, can you explain? Thanks

Comment: Are we looking for solutions for $z$ satisfying both (a) and (b) at the same time, or are we looking for solutions for $z$ satisfying (a) and then those satisfying (b)? Is it one or two problems? (Does this help?)

Comment: no no it's 2 problems, I understand now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way to solve these equations:

(a)  Obviously  $i$ is a cubic root of $-i$. So all  cubic roots of $-i$ are obtained by multiplication of this root by the cubic roots of unity: $\;1$, $j=\mathrm e^{\tfrac{2i\pi}3}$ and $j^2=\mathrm e^{\tfrac{4i\pi}3}=\mathrm e^{-\tfrac{2i\pi}3}$.

(b) Set $Z=z^2$. Solving first $Z^2+Z+1=0$, we obtain the non-real cubic roots of unity, $j$ and $j^2$. So  $z$ is one of the square roots of $j$ and $j^2$, $\pm j^2$ and $\pm j$ respectively.

Comment: But for (a), the equation have 4 roots true? (4-th degree), is it $j=e^{{2k\pi \over 3}i}$ , $k=0,1,2,3$ so $j_1=1$ , $j_2=e^{{2\pi \over 3}i}$ , $j_3=e^{{4\pi \over 3}i}$ and $j_4=e^{{6\pi \over 3}i}$ ?

Comment: (a) is an equation of degree 3, not 4.

Comment: Oh sorry, you're right, but how you calculate $\theta$ in (a) ? Is it $={2\pi \over 3}$ or ${3\pi \over 3}$ or $2\pi$.

Comment: Just use  $i=\mathrm e^{\tfrac{i\pi}2}$ and  the exponential form of $j$ and $j^2$.

Comment: Ok last question, for (b), $j_1={1\over 2}+{\sqrt{3}\over 2}i$, $j_2={1\over 2}-{\sqrt{3}\over 2}i$ , but what about $+j^2$ and $-j^2$ ? I am sorry and thank you so much.

Comment: That's  quite simple: $j^2=\bar  j$  (don't forget $j$ and $j^2$  are roots of $z^2+z+1$, a polynomial with real coefficients) and of course $\;-j^2=-\bar j$.

Comment: So the four roots of $z^4+z^2+1=0$ is $z_1={-1\over 2}+{{\sqrt{3}i}\over 2}$ , $z_2=-({-1\over 2}+{{\sqrt{3}i}\over 2})$ , $z_3={-1\over 2}-{{\sqrt{3}i}\over 2}$ and $z_4=-({-1\over 2}-{{\sqrt{3}i}\over 2})$ , if it is wrong i am so sorry but it hard :(

Comment: It's correct. You should simplify the last root. B.t.w., I've just seen I had swapped the square roots in my answer  (I've fixed it now).

Answer (score 1):

You have $-i=\cos\frac{3\pi}{2}+i\sin\frac{3\pi}{2}$, not with $\pi/2$.

So the roots of $z^3=-i$ are
$$
\cos\left(\frac{3\pi}{6}+\frac{2k\pi}{3}\right)+
i\sin\left(\frac{3\pi}{6}+\frac{2k\pi}{3}\right)
$$
for $k=0,1,2$.

Note, for instance, that $(\cos(\pi/6)+i\sin(\pi/6))^3=i$, not $-i$.

For the second equation, first solve $w^2+w+1=0$, which has the roots
$$
w_1=-\frac{1}{2}+i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}=
\cos\frac{2\pi}{3}+i\sin\frac{2\pi}{3}
\qquad\text{and}\qquad
w_2=-\frac{1}{2}-i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}=\cos\frac{4\pi}{3}+i\sin\frac{4\pi}{3}
$$
Now compute the square roots with De Moivre's formula.

Comment: Thank you, but in first answer why ${3\pi \over 2}$ ? , how you calculate it? $arctan (-\infty) = -{\pi\over 2}$ so how you found ${3\pi\over 2}$?

Comment: @Dima $3\pi/2$ is as good as $-\pi/2$, because they refer to the same angle (modulo $2\pi$). On the other hand, the arctangent method does not always correctly identify the angle, because it only catches the first and fourth quadrants.